# Sharing on facebook feed with jquery, how to change content

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here's my problem: there is a 'share on facebook' button on a website I was tasked to tweak. One of the things that need changing is the content of the share, it actually needs to be dynamic, based on the users action on the page.

I prevented the default behaviour on the button and am trying to use the FB.ui feed method to change what is being shared. Here is the code thats executed on button click:

```
$("#elem").click(function(e){
    FB.ui({
      method: "feed",
      name: "Test tes Test",
      link: "https://www.example.com/example/",
      picture: "https://www.example.com/example.png",
      caption: "Example.com",
      description: "msg",
      message: "msg"
    }, function(response){});
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

of course I load the facebook sdk and connect with an app without any issues beforehand.

This soultion does change the layout of the sharing popup, but that's it. The picture and the description remain the way they were originally. I am running out of ideas on how to tackle this and will be very greatful for any help.

Comment: What URL are you sharing - just an external website, or a Facebook page, ...?

Comment: it is the page that the share originates from

Comment: Does the same happen when your call that function not from the original FB share button, but on some other element?

Comment: It actually did help! Why? the descriptions, captions etc change to the ones I provide. Unfortunately the picture stays the same and that is one of the most important things here.

Comment: Dunno, but I think adding event handlers to the buttons Facebook provides might easily lead to overlaps in functionality ... That it doesn’t take the picture might be a caching issue. Make sure it is large enough (at least 200 by 200 px), and maybe try and put the image URL through the debug tool, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/